# Send data from one action to another in ZF in URL without forms

Tags: php, url, zend-framework, hyperlink

I want to get the data of a textbox that is on `a.phtml`, and the receiving action is `b` and its view is `b.phtml` by using the hyper link that should be in `a.phtml`. How could I get this.

**Example**

**a.phtml**

```
<input type='text' id='username' name="username">
<a href="b">hassan</a>
```

b.phtml will be an iframe
how could I get the value of text box by this method.

Comment: do you want to post your data with ajax.

Comment: Actually I have a table that contains with the cities and a count and date, user can change the date and ask to show the graph according to the date. I want to send that asked date from URL so that it should show the right graph.... Graph will show in iframe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am able to understand your problem. You can create a `javascript` `function` and call that from anchor tag.

```
function myfunction(){
  var name = $('#username').val();

  // use ajax here to pass your values to different action

  // or if just want to redirect with data then 
  window.location.href = '/controller/action/param/'+ name; 
}

<input type='text' id='username' name="username">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myfunction()">hassan</a>
```

Not sure you are using jquery or not.